# Should there be some kind of special award for the 10 millionth question?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't help that the SO question count is getting close to 10M!  Hooray!  Should there be a prize awarded to the asker of that milestone question?

Comment: Do you want to encourage people to think of it like a badge, with whatever questionable content might result as that otherwise arbitrary number approaches?

Comment: I suppose it could result in a bit of trolling, but it seems to me that it's a somewhat respectable stat.  It could be something simple outside of the website, too.  For instance, a couple years ago, BitBucket acquired 1M users and released a t-shirt that was only available to those members.

Comment: Sorry. An award for this would encourage idiotic questions being posted in order to try to be the recipient. We get enough idiotic questions already without encouraging more.

Comment: Maybe you can do an anti-award, like a "It took you long enough" badge that's awarded to new members after the milestone is reached.  I just thought there was an opportunity to have some fun.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is that just SO posts, or is that SE-wide?

Comment: What happens if the 10-millionth question gets deleted? Would the one after it be awarded? Will it still be the 10-millionth question if one before it gets deleted? Could deleting cause multiple 10-millionth questions? Including deleted ones, there must be 10 million questions already.

Comment: Is what "just SO posts, or is that SE wide?"? SE wide, there are a lot of poor questions that are closed, and at SO specifically we get a large amount of garbage that needs to be cleaned up. Encouraging more by trying to *have some fun* just means more work to keep the noise and clutter down here. Attracting trash in order to get an award is counter-productive. What's next? An award for getting the most votes for being  spam? The most votes for being unable to Google? The most amount of letters that make actual words?

Comment: I think that a prize shouldn't be given out, but maybe the post should be labelled or given an identifying feature. I agree that many people would post spam to try to get the "prize", but this may be fixed by hiding the amount of questions posted until the 10 millionth is hit. Just a thought..

Comment: Ken, I think you're going off the deep end with this.  It seemed like an important thing.  Apparently it's not.  Or rather, it's more important to maintain the integrity of the site than to celebrate some "arbitrary number" of questions.  I agree with that, but at the same time, it seemed an appropriate question to ask.  And now it has been, and it seems we have an answer.  The site has completed its mission.

Comment: An answer would seem appropriate

Comment: Someone should run a book on whether the 10-millionth question is going to be VLQ.

Comment: Actually, the 10 million mark has long been surpassed if you include deleted questions.

Comment: Why are people downvoting my question?  It follows the guidelines perfectly.  I thought voting was supposed to reflect the quality of the question.  It's well-stated.  The fact that it may be a bad idea doesn't detract from it's quality.

Comment: @gregsdennis voting on meta is different. In you case people vote because it means they are not considering your idea something worth pursuing, not because the question is flawed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Absolutely not. An award for this would encourage idiotic questions being posted in order to try to be the recipient. We get enough idiotic questions already without encouraging more of them.

This site isn't about earning *awards* or anything else. It's about collecting knowledge that can be shared. Awarding people just for posting some *milestone* question is counter-productive. Do we award people for posting the question with the most letters that don't make words? The people who post the question that shows the least amount of effort to solve themselves? The most blatant copy/paste of homework? No, because it's noise and cluttter that we don't want.

Comment: And yet something was done anyway.  http://stackoverflow.com/10m

Answer (score 3):

We will be celebrating the momentous event *in general*, here on meta, in a manner that doesn't create noise on the main site (beyond something in the community bulletin inviting anyone that cares here). It will be a celebration for *everyone*, not just the person that asked the question - we're just happy it happened.

Think of it like a conference where they feed you; some tables have pizza, some have noodles, some have grilled stuff and some have mind-blowing apple juice in unlimited quantities.

*It will likely happen shortly after the event, because such things are nearly impossible to time*, but we will be doing something :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/10m